# Promesa y perdida de contexto de la posicion[i] en un ciclo For

Tags: javascript

Me pasa lo siguiente:
en un ciclo recorro un arreglo, y por medio de un parámetro pretendo ir a buscar una data para setear un dato del arreglo todo bien.
ejemplo:

```
for(var i = 0; ...[arr]...i++){
    var promesa = metodoGet(...)then(return promesa);
    resuelvo esta promesa y aqui es donde tengo el problema:

    promise = promesa;

    promise.then(function(resp){ 
        AQUI ES DONDE QUIERO SETEAR UN DATO DEL ARREGLO PERO no puedo acceder a 
        la posicion [i] del arreglo porque no lo reconoce(undefined) 

        console.log($scope.arr[i].dato); //undefined

        //pero si me muestra el arreglo completo.
        console.log($scope.arr) //[{...}]
    });//fin then();

}//Fin FOR
```

**como puedo hacer para que me tome la posicion[i] del arreglo y asi poder setear el valor correctamente?
mejor dicho no quiero que el resultado de mi `get()` sea una promesa sino mas bien un objeto el cual pueda acceder sin tener que resolver una promesa**

cod:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.succeeded.length; i++) {
  var resultado = $http.get('/api/arreglo/codigo/' + 
  $scope.succeeded[i].dato).then( (res) => {
    //aqui se pierde el contexto de mi arreglo y posicion
    //y aqui es donde quiero setear el arreglo

    return res.data[0].id;//retorno de GET()
  });

  promise = resultado;

  promise.then(function(resp){
    //aqui al resolver la promesa pierdo el contexto de la posicion[i]  
    console.log("RESP ", resp); //la respuesta del GET()
    console.log("SCOPE ON PROMISE", $scope.succeeded);//aqui me muestra todo el arreglo

    //esto no lo puedo hacer y es lo que necesito
    $scope.succeeded[i].dato = resp.dato;
  });
```

No tengo claro el porque se pierde el contexto del ciclo `for`, en este caso la posicion[i] del arreglo recorrido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien asumís tenés una pérdida de contexto en tu bucle, esto se produce debido a una característica de javascript llamada hoisting, lo que hace el hoisting básicamante es mover todas las declaraciones de variables lo más arriba posible dentro de la función en la que se declaran, en este caso la variable `i` la estás declarando dentro del `for` lo que hace que se mueva fuera del mismo y la convierte en una especie de variable "global" ya que el for no es una función, por lo tanto en el momento que se resuelve la promesa la variable `i` ya cambió.

Para subsanar este problema tenés dos posibilidades, metés una `iife`(función inmediatamente invocada) que guarda el contexto de la variable `i` valiendose de las closures dentro del bucle o declaras a la variable `i` con la palabra clave `let` en lugar de `var`.

`let` tiene solo alcance de bloque, en este caso vive solo dentro del bucle `for` y no tiene hoisting como si lo tienen las variables declaradas como `var`

te dejo 3 ejemplos para que los veas en acción, el primer caso como verás utiliza la declaración con `var` y no funciona como uno esperaría de hecho imprime un valor que ni siquiera se utiliza dentro del bucle `for`, el segundo caso también se declara con `var`, pero hay una `iife` y funciona como uno esperaría y en el tercer caso también funciona bien, pero se declara usando la palabra clave `let`.

Consejo, dejar de usar `var` y empezar a usar `let` y `const` para declarar variables

```js
for (var index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
  let promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000);
  });
  promise.then(() => console.log("con var", index));
}

for (var index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
  (function(index) {
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000);
    });
    promise.then(() => console.log("con iife", index));
  })(index);
}

for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
  let promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000);
  });
  promise.then(() => console.log("con let", index));
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, lo probe y funciono, era la declaracion de i. Te pasaste compadre. seguire tu consejo de utilizar let y const.